# How to properly use variable in ggplot?

Tags: r, variables, ggplot2, aesthetics

I have found an issue, that I was unable to understand. Can someone please point to an explanation?

In ggplot, if I use/don't use  "$" with variable name , it gives different result. Please see the example below,

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.csv("pseudo_facebook.tsv", sep = '\t')

# Without $ sign
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = friend_count)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 25) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 1000), breaks = seq(0, 1000, 25)) + 
  facet_grid(~df$gender)
```

[image: Without $ in the variable name]

```
# With $ sign
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = df$friend_count)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 25) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 1000), breaks = seq(0, 1000, 25)) + 
  facet_grid(~df$gender)
```

[image]

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example for a question like this. Run `dput(df)` and copy the output into the question (providing the dataset isn't too big).

Comment: The short explanation is: never use `$` inside aes() or in faceting! Just don't do it! It is wrong! ;)

Comment: Hi, 
This is the file used for the data,
https://github.com/staceynlee/Pseudo-Facebook-Data-Udacity/blob/master/pseudo_facebook%20(1).tsv

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what's causing your behaviour, but in the first example, you still have `df$` in the `facet_grid` formula. It's possible there's some sneaky evaluation problem going on if you're mixing bare column names on their own with column names specified with the data frame.

If you switch out that filename in `read.csv` with a URL, you'll have a reprex that I can test

Comment: Here is the data source link, if you mean that?
https://github.com/staceynlee/Pseudo-Facebook-Data-Udacity/blob/master/pseudo_facebook%20(1).tsv